# R: Create correlation map between spreadsheet and netcdf dataset

Tags: r, correlation, netcdf

I am stuck and could not find a solution anywhere. I would like to create a **simple correlation map** such as [this one](http://datascience-enthusiast.com/figures/correlation.png) **between my data**, which is basically a list/ excel spreadsheet of daily rainfall values from a certain location for the month of January 2010 **and a netcdf dataset** with daily rainfall values for West Africa for the same time period. The netcdf dataset TRMM is available [here](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.NASA/.GES-DAAC/.TRMM_L3/.TRMM_3B42/.v7/.daily/.precipitation/T/4383.5/4413.5/RANGE/X/340.0/380.0/RANGEEDGES/Y/-5/24/RANGEEDGES/datafiles.html)  and can be downloaded by clicking on the blue link saying "netCDF". 
My spreedsheet data is from Accra, Ghana (lat:5.6N, lon:-0.22W) and looks like this:

```
- Date, Rainfall
- 2010-01-01, 5.5
- 2010-01-02, 3
- 2010-01-03, 0
- 2010-01-04, 7
- 2010-01-05, NA
- 2010-01-06, 0
- ...
- 2010-01-31, 4.5
```

I loaded the netcdf file as a `raster::brick`, but I am not sure how to deal with my data from Ghana in order to calculate the correlation between both datasets.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to solving a problem like this is to create a small example with simple data so that you get the understand the principle. For example:

```
# example data 
library(raster)
set.seed(424)
b <- brick(nrow=10, ncol=10, nl=100)
values(b) <- matrix(runif(100*100, max=100), 100, 100)   
rain <- runif(100, max=100)

# function to compute correlation between rain and RasterBrick values
fun <- function(x) cor(as.vector(x), rain)

# use the function with calc
r <- calc(b, fun)
plot(r)
```